# Вывести строки массива json по отдельности

Tags: php, json, foreach

Есть Json массив, `$json = json_decode($content, true);` выводится он в таком виде:

```
array(2) { 
     ["status"]=> int(1) 
     ["balance"]=> array(3) { 
        ["balance"]=> array(3) {
            ["RUB"]=> int(0)
            ["USD"]=> int(0) 
            ["EUR"]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["hold"]=> array(3) { 
            ["RUB"]=> int(0) 
            ["USD"]=> int(0) 
            ["EUR"]=> int(0) 
        } 
        ["available"]=> array(3) { 
            ["RUB"]=> int(0) 
            ["USD"]=> int(0) 
            ["EUR"]=> int(0) 
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно каждые записи, например с `balance` вывести `RUB` не через `foreach` а отдельным тегом через `echo`.

Сейчас же выводится через `foreach`

```
foreach($json['balance'] as $key=>$val){ 
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'RUB - ' . $val['RUB'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'USD - ' . $val['USD'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'EUR - ' . $val['EUR'];

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести по отдельности? Сам пробовал, отдает пустую строку. как бы не пытался вывести отдельным тегом.

Comment: Что значит "отдельным тегом"?

Comment: `$json['balance']['balance']['RUB']`

Comment: @u_mulder ненавижу вот такой неструктурированный вывод читать :) Как бы всех приучить var_export пользовать

Comment: лучше напишите, какую верстку хотите получить, а не это невнятное описание

Comment: @teran Вёрстка такого плана: рубль: 0 RUB и т. Д.

Comment: @u_mulder  ответил тут. Каждое значение выводить отдельно. Не циклом. Без цикла

Comment: Ну вам во втором комментарии написали. Хотя что плохого в цикле - неясно.